# React. Child component is changing parent component

Tags: reactjs, state

so i have a child component inside a parent one, and i wanna pass a clone of state to the child comp and performe some actions on it, but what im getting is when i change the child component the state of the parent comp change as well, and i dont want that i want them to be separated. Call to child comp :  `<UpdateTasksModal Tasks={this.state.Tasks.filter(x => x.selected == true)} />`
Child comp :

```
const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.Tasks)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTasks( props.Tasks )
    }, [props.Tasks])


    function handleTaskChange(e, index){
        let newTasks = Tasks
        newTasks[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value
        setTasks([...newTasks])
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's what you really want to do. What if, after you change child component tasks, parent component changes the same prop? It will override your child change... What's the use case anyway?

Comment: the use case is the user can update the tasks and to update it he needs to click on validate button, but since it was changing the parent prop on any change that made a problem

Comment: Well then you shouldn't update tasks directly in child component. Child component should be a form that will output the change to the parent, and parent should handle the tasks change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the spread operator to clone props, it is a shadow clone. If you really want to have a deep clone, try to use

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.Task))`